# How can I use cropme.js to allow users upload their profile image?

Tags: javascript, crop

This is a knowledge sharing Q&A.

[Cropme](https://github.com/shpontex/cropme) is a nice JS add-on for cropping and rotating an image using visual sliders. The author provided good documentation, but building a working implementation is not as simple as it should be.

The question I want to answer is this:

I want to allow my website-users to upload their profile image. That image must be exactly 240x292 pixels. The users should be able zoom and rotate their image, then crop it to that specific size and upload it to my website. How can I do all that with cropme?

These are the requires steps:

1. Show an empty placeholder for the image we want the user to load.
2. By clicking the "Get Image" button, the user can select an image from its local files.
3. The selected file is loaded into memory, and presented for editing using 'cropme'. The user can use visual sliders to rotate and zoom in/out
4. After clicking "Crop", the user is presented with the cropped image, and can decide to save the image or to cancel.
5. After clicking "Save", the cropped image is uploaded to a PHP server, the modal window is closed, and the placeholder image is replaced with the link to the just-uploaded image.

So how can we do this?

[image: Cropme modal-popup used for on-the-fly editing]

Answer (score 1):

#### A fully working demo is presented here:

https://codepen.io/ishahak/pen/XWjVzLr

I will explain some of the details, step by step.

Note: usually in my code when you see *obj[0]*, it is simply a conversion from jQuery object into a simple JS object.

#### 1. Showing a placeholder for the image.

We can create a real SVG image on the fly using this code:

```
getImagePlaceholder: function(width, height, text) {
  //based on https://cloudfour.com/thinks/simple-svg-placeholder/
  var svg = '\
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="{w}" \
    height="{h}" viewBox="0 0 {w} {h}">\
    <rect fill="#ddd" width="{w}" height="{h}"/>\
    <text fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)" font-family="sans-serif"\
    font-size="30" dy="10.5" font-weight="bold"\
    x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle">{t}</text>\
    </svg>';
  var cleaned = svg
    .replace(/{w}/g, width)
    .replace(/{h}/g, height)
    .replace('{t}', text)
    .replace(/[\t\n\r]/gim, '') // Strip newlines and tabs
    .replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ') // Condense multiple spaces
    .replace(/'/gim, '\\i'); // Normalize quotes

  var encoded = encodeURIComponent(cleaned)
    .replace(/\(/g, '%28') // Encode brackets
    .replace(/\)/g, '%29');

  return 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,' + encoded;
}
```

#### 2. By clicking the "Get Image" button, the user can select an image from its local files.

This process involves an input element of type "file" which has no visible appearance (we set it with the 'd-none' class), and a button element which 'clicks' it to open a dialog:

```
  <button id="btnGetImage" class="btn btn-primary">Get Image</button>
  <input class="d-none" type="file" id="fileUpload" accept="image/*" />
```

And the relevant code:

```
$('#btnGetImage').on('click', function(){
  //force 'change' event even if repeating same file:
  $('#fileUpload').prop("value", ""); 
  $('#fileUpload').click();
});
$('#fileUpload').on('change', function(){
  CiM.read_file_from_input(/*input elem*/this, function() {
    console.log('image src fully loaded');
    $('#imgModal-dialog').modal('show');
  });           
});
```

When a file is selected, the 'change' event is firing, leading us to read the file into memory.

#### 3. The selected file is loaded into memory, and presented for editing using 'cropme'. The user can use visual sliders to rotate and zoom in/out

Our *read_file_from_input* mentioned above is implemented like this:

```
imgHolder: null,
imgHolderCallback: null,
read_file_from_input: function(input, callback) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      imgHolderCallback = callback;
      var reader = new FileReader();
      if (!CiM.imgHolder) {
        CiM.imgHolder = new Image();
        CiM.imgHolder.onload = function () {
           if (imgHolderCallback) { 
             imgHolderCallback();
           }
        }
      }
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        console.log('image data loaded!');
        CiM.imgHolder.src = e.target.result; //listen to img:load...
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
  else {
    console.warn('failed to read file');
  }
}
```

When the FileReader is ready, we set the *src* for our internal image holder, and wait for the 'load' event, which signals that the *img* element is ready with the new content.

We listen to that 'load' event, and when triggered we show the modal. A modal in Bootstrap has several events. We listen to the one which signals that the modal is shown, meaning that the width and set and we can plan our Cropme dimensions based on it.

```
update_options_for_width: function(w) {
  var o = CiM.opt, //shortcut
      vp_ratio = o.my_final_size.w / o.my_final_size.h,
      h, new_vp_w, new_vp_h;
  w = Math.floor(w * 0.9);
  h = Math.floor(w / o.my_win_ratio);
  o.container.width = w;
  o.container.height = h;
  new_vp_h = 0.6 * h;
  new_vp_w = new_vp_h * vp_ratio;
  // if we adapted to the height, but it's too wide:
  if (new_vp_w > 0.6 * w) { 
    new_vp_w = 0.6 * w;
    new_vp_h = new_vp_w / vp_ratio;
  }
  new_vp_w = Math.floor(new_vp_w);
  new_vp_h = Math.floor(new_vp_h);
  o.viewport.height = new_vp_h;
  o.viewport.width = new_vp_w;    
}
```

We wait for the size of the modal to be set because *cropme* must be set with specific viewport dimensions. At the end of our *shown.bs.modal* handler, we create our *Cropme* instance.

#### 4. After clicking "Crop", the user is presented with the cropped image, and can decide to save the image or to cancel.

Here is the save-button handler:

```
$('#imgModal-btnSave').on('click', function(){
  uploadImage(croppedImg[0], function(path_to_saved) {
    savedImg[0].src = path_to_saved;
    $('#imgModal-dialog').modal('hide');
  });
});
```

The *uploadImage* function goes like this:

```
uploadImage: function(img, callback){
  var imgCanvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
  imgContext = imgCanvas.getContext("2d");

  // Make sure canvas is as big as the picture (needed??)
  imgCanvas.width = img.width;
  imgCanvas.height = img.height;

  // Draw image into canvas element
  imgContext.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

  var dataURL = imgCanvas.toDataURL();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "save-img.php", // see code at the bottom
    data: { 
       imgBase64: dataURL
    }
  }).done(function(resp) {
    if (resp.startsWith('nok')) {
      console.warn('got save error:', resp);
    } else {
      if (callback) callback(resp);
    }
  });
}
```

It is matched with a simple PHP script which appears at the end of the HTML in the *codepen*. I think this answer went too long, so I'll finish here.

Good luck - have fun :)