# Allow user to upload image with crop, sizing and positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to find a JavaScript library that allows a user to upload a profile picture but also allows a user to resize or reposition the image so that it better fits a view port. (Think LinkedIn profile picture or an Instagram image upload).

[image]

Are there any open source js libraries available that handle this? If so, how can I then save that zoom/positioning so that every time that image is called it retains those properties?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: I'm afraid library suggestion questions are off topic for this site. (Mainly since they don't age well and can be heavily opinion based)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use HTML5 to resize an image before upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945494/use-html5-to-resize-an-image-before-upload)

Comment: @Lukky Not quite. I'd rather not actually resize the image, but instead leave the image and retain the zoom and positioning so that a user could go back later and edit the zoom and positioning if need be.

Comment: [ImagerJS](https://www.imagerjs.com/) check this library out

Comment: Found a useful library in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65490868/how-can-i-use-cropme-js-to-allow-users-upload-their-profile-image